Using with_expression() to populate instance on one side of many-to-many relationship from association table
I have two entities User and Group linked together in many-to-many relationship with an association table with extra column ("position"). As records in the association table are unique in regard to User-Group pairs, I'd like to be able to populate User entity with data from the association table.
I thought I could achieve that by using query_expression() along with with_expression(). Here are my models.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, literal, select, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy, AssociationProxy
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    DeclarativeBase, declared_attr, Mapped, mapped_column, query_expression,
    relationship, selectinload, Session
)


class Base(DeclarativeBase):

    @declared_attr.directive
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        return cls.__name__.lower()


class User(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    user_groups: Mapped[list['UserGroup']] = relationship(
        'UserGroup', back_populates='user'
    )
    position: Mapped[str | None] = query_expression()

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'User(id={self.id}, name={self.name})'


class Group(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    group_users: Mapped[list['UserGroup']] = relationship(
        'UserGroup', back_populates='group'
    )
    users: AssociationProxy[list['User']] = association_proxy(
        target_collection='group_users', attr='user'
    )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Group(id={self.id}, title={self.title})'


class UserGroup(Base):
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True
    )
    group_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("group.id"), primary_key=True
    )
    position: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()

    group = relationship('Group', back_populates='group_users')
    user = relationship('User', back_populates='user_groups')

What I want to achieve is to have position inside User entities when querying for a Group. So group.users[0].position contains user's position in that group.  The best I can get so far is that
group = session.execute(
    select(Group).options(
        selectinload(Group.group_users).joinedload(UserGroup.user)
        .with_expression(User.position, UserGroup.position)
    ).where(Group.id == 1)).scalar_one()

But it inserts None into User instead of the actual data. If I replace the second parameter of with_expression with literal("anything"), it works. So I may conclude that the problem is getting proper value from the UserGroup model.
Sample code if you want to try:
engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", echo=False)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

user_1 = User(name="Bob")
user_2 = User(name="Ben")
group_1 = Group(title="Editors")
position_1 = UserGroup(user=user_1, group=group_1, position="Senior")
position_2 = UserGroup(user=user_2, group=group_1, position="Junior")

session = Session(bind=engine)
session.add_all([user_1, user_2, group_1, position_1, position_2])
session.commit()

group = session.execute(
    select(Group).options(
        selectinload(Group.group_users).joinedload(UserGroup.user)
        .with_expression(User.position, UserGroup.position)
    ).where(Group.id == 1)).scalar_one()

print(f'Members of group {group.title}:')
for user in group.users:
    print(f'User.name={user.name}, User.position={user.position}')

Any thought on how to get working?

I'm posting a solution I developed, but not totally satisfied with. May be it will inspire someone to find a better one.
group = session.scalar(
        select(Group, User)
        .join_from(UserGroup, Group)
        .join_from(UserGroup, User)
        .options(with_expression(User.position, UserGroup.position))
        .where(Group.id == 1)
    )

The select statement requests both Group and User entities so that with_expression can find User to fill in. The result of execution of the statement is a sequence of rows (as many as are users in the group) of (Group, User) tuples. The scalar function gets first item from the first row, that is Group we are looking for.
It emits two queries. First at the scalar call and it is enough to access Group attributes:
SELECT "group".id, "group".title, usergroup.position, user.id AS id_1, user.name
FROM usergroup JOIN "group" ON "group".id = usergroup.group_id JOIN user ON user.id = usergroup.user_id
WHERE "group".id = ?

Second, when we access Group.users, which is a bit upsetting, because it already has all the info from the first query:
SELECT usergroup.user_id AS usergroup_user_id, usergroup.group_id AS usergroup_group_id, usergroup.position AS usergroup_position 
FROM usergroup
WHERE ? = usergroup.group_id

The User objects seem to be filled properly:
User.name=Bob, User.position=Senior
User.name=Ben, User.position=Junior

A bit of insight of why the second request is fired. It happens when you walk across relationship from Group to UserGroup. The logic behind it is that ORM wants to know what UserGroup and subsequently User records are linked to the Group object under consideration. After receiving necessary ids, it sees that corresponding User objects are already loaded into the Session and gives output.
The ORM could have cached the relationship information with the first query, but it didn't.
